Guarantee SQL Management Studio Query
When running a query in SQL Server Management Studio, is it then possible to guarantee that the script will only target the designated database?
When I select a database, that's fine and good and all - but when discussing with Change Management, it would be easier to tell them: See, I set this checkmark, now the script can't touch anything but the test database.
What do people do? Create a management user per database? Ignore the problem?
Is it a problem at all? When I discussed it with our internal DBA, he seemed a little baffled by the question.

Sounds to me like you (and Change Management) are concerned about people running SQL directly in your [Production] databases and making changes to the wrong database.
Management Studio cannot directly help you here.
If someone as allowed to do something, then SSMS will let them.
What you need is something more like this:

Proper access control.
Only allow people who know what they're doing anywhere near your databases.
Grant those people relevant permissions in each Environment - everything in DEV, progressively less in TEST and very little (or nothing) in Production.

Automated upgrades.
Build an automated "pipeline" through which schema changes can be submitted and applied to databases.  All changes are scripted in DEV and "pushed" through this pipeline to any other database.  The target databases are configured as part of that pipeline and cannot be "accidentally" changed as things go through.



It's a little unclear what you're asking but let me do my best to address each of your questions:

When running a query in SQL Server Management Studio, is it then possible to guarantee that the script will only target the designated database?

No, not really.
These are some of the features (in no particular order) that can cause other databases to be affected when you run a query, depending on what kind of query you're running:

Triggers
Cross-database references
Linked Servers
Polybase connections
Replication
Availability Groups
Shared Storage
Change Data Capture
Temporal Tables
Change Tracking
SQL Agent Jobs
External Jobs
CLR
Etc etc

This is regardless if your query explicitly sets the database context or even calls out every object with the 3-part name to explicitly use the database name in the reference.
Not to mention, depending on the type of query, if it's resource intensive, that'll consume resources from the server which are shared among the other databases, and could possibly cause contention.

What do people do? Create a management user per database?

Proper access controls should always be put in place so minimum necessary access is available to each user.

Is it a problem at all?

Not when only competent people who know the database and know the code they're running are the ones actually executing the code.
